# Blurred Effect option for Portrait Mode on iOS11?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

Did we lose the Blurred Effect option for Portrait Mode on iOS11? My iPhone X I noticed this morning when I wanted to use that feature, Under Portrait Mode it just as the studio options now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the default option (pre iOS 11) was changed to "Natural Light" in iOS 11. Try that option...